# C++ Builder Exception - StackTrace empty?

Tags: c++, exception, c++builder, stack-trace, c++builder-xe2

I want to get the stack trace but it is always empty?

```
try{
    int a = 5, b = 0;
    int c = a/b;
}
catch(Exception &e){
    ShowMessage("Exception: " + e.Message + "\nStackTrace:" + e.StackTrace);
}
```

Using C++ Builder XE2.

Edit: This code executes on TForm1::Button1Click.

Comment: Are you in your main-function?

Comment: Are you sure a divide by zero results in `Exception` being thrown?

Comment: Yes, exception is thrown. I updated the post.

Comment: Isn't is `ShowMessage("Exception: " + e.Message() + "\nStackTrace:" + e.StackTrace());`?

Comment: No. StackTrace is UnicodeString (data member).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here:
https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=419807&tstart=0

*However, the property returns an empty string by default. It is designed
so third-party exception loggers (MadExcept, EurekaLog, etc) can hook into
it to provide the actual stack trace information. Why Embarcadero has chosen
not to provide their own native implementation is anyone's guess.*

Comment: Like the answer says, you have to use a third-party solution, like one of the products listed, or write your own from scratch. Embarcadero does not provide a native stack tracer of their own.

Comment: Remove the additional question from your answer and mark it as accepted. Other SO users won't notice your question unless it is asked separately. If you want to know how to implement a stack trace using the hooks Embarcadero provided the best way is to implement it youself then create a new question if/when you get stuck.

Comment: The link above into the Embarcadero forum is broken. Can anyone provide a corrected link, or a cached copy of the forum entry?

Comment: Link to official wiki: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.Exception.StackTrace